# Line wrapping in PowerShell ISE Console?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I sometimes write long lines of code as I am playing with things in the PowerShell ISE (v4 on Windows 8.1). I find its console window helpful in many ways, but I'm unable to figure out how to make it wrap long lines; it makes me use my mouse when I only want to use the keyboard.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to enable automatic line wrapping in the PowerShell ISE? Failing that, can I scroll left/right using the keyboard?

*Note: this is a separate question from how to split a command across multiple lines using the backtick (`) operator.*

Comment: You might like to try ConEmu. It has automatic line wrapping.

Comment: @dangph Thanks - I may take a look at that. With PSReadLine it will have some form of the intellisense that I like from the ISE. I may also just wait for Windows 10 to see how powershell and the ISE work with their new console.

Comment: yeah, PSReadLine is great. One thing in particular that I like about it is the Bash style command history as opposed to the DOS style in the ISE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, ISE does not have this functionality... which is weird given that PowerShell (Non-ISE) does.

Unfortunately - the Windows 10/PowerShell 5 ISE isn't any better.  The only possible solutions are:

- Tilde/Backtick (`) - which you've already said you know about
- Use the ISE "Copy" function when building a command in the cmdlet explorer and then paste into a separate console - hardly ideal, but it may work
- Develop in a third party application such as Notepad++ and test in ISE/PowerShell
- Work in the non ISE PowerShell command prompt and use tab completion instead of Intellisense.
- Investiagte some other ISE such as PowerShell Studio (paid) which seems to wrap lines OK according to a colleague of mine

Sorry I can't be of any more help.

Comment: That's truly sad.

Answer (score 0):

Word wrap is not supported. You may eliminate the need to scroll to the right to see a complete command by changing the Font size. Go to the Tools tab and decrease the font size.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).